# Verify a hashed password

Tags: python, hash

I'm hashing a password as follows:

```
mysalt = os.urandom(12).encode('hex')
passhash = mysalt + pw
hash = str(pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(passhash))
```

How can I verify this password with user entry? The following:

```
hash3 = str(pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(passhash))
```

...returns a completely different value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is hard to make sense from that code if you do not add some formatting.

Comment: I hope you are using the same salt and not trying with a new salt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use the same salt when you store the password as when you're checking it: `passhash` values with different salts will result in different hashes.

You could either use the same salt for every password (more convenient), use and store a different salt for every user (more secure), or a combination of both.

---

Edit: You didn't specify which library you were using to get `pbkdf2_sha256`. It could be that that library can handle salt-related tasks by itself. [PassLib](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html), for example, will generate a salt for you and include it in the result. It offers a `verify` method to check the user's input against that result.

Answer (score 0):

Would advise against comparing the resulting strings - often encoding gets in the way. Try comparing the actual bytes.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:

```
import os
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
mysalt=os.urandom(12).encode('hex')

hash = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt("password")
print hash

print pbkdf2_sha256.verify("password", hash)

pwd='sefrhiloliutzrthgrfsdyv<sef234244567!"234wsdycvhn'

mypass =mysalt+pwd

print mypass

hash2   =pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(mypass, rounds =200000)
hash1= pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(pwd, rounds=80000, salt_size=100)

print"hash2: ", hash2
print pbkdf2_sha256.verify(mypass,hash2)
```